# how to clone table row with one way binding in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm new to angular js. i'm need to add new row in table to get different values from textbox. i am using custom directive with transclude template. New row is added but all textbox binding same value when i typing on textbox.

Comment: my working demo is http://plnkr.co/edit/MZs2jmLUiXwYMBqhveUt?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to have custom directive, I edited your plunker.http://plnkr.co/edit/WEhaTQFYeWHKZYSeGDdL?p=preview

The goal is to create in scope a structure to get values :

```
$scope.rows = [{}]
$scope.addnewrow = function(){
           $scope.rows.push({})
        };
```

And use ng-repeat to dislay data